# Why does my code not find directories

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, directory

**EDIT:
It has been pointed out that my code does actually kind of work. But it identifies the 'this.zip' file as a subfolder, so any folder that is 'contents\this.zip' is listed which is not what I want. (Trying to only find those that are 'contents\newfolder\this.zip', so there is at least one sub folder of the 'contents' directory). How can I get it to only list the directories that are actual folders, and not just .zip files?

I am writing a program that deals with files titled 'this.zip' which are typically directly located in a folder called 'contents' . I am trying to determine if the this.zip file is directly in the 'contents' folder, or if there is a subfolder it is within. I have a set of code that is working to determine if the 'contents' folder is empty, and I thought that I could change it to find any 'contents'  folders that contain subdirectories, but it's not working.

```
//This finds 'contents' folders that are empty
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(txtbxOldFolder.Text);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories("*contents*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);                

            Var query = from folder in folders
                        where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length == 0
                        select folder.FullName.ToString();
            foreach (string str in query)
            {
                //this adds the path of any empty 'contents' folder
                listEmptyFolder.Add(str);
            }
```

I thought if I changed the the query - where statement to be a length > 1 it would find any that have subdirectories, but it's not working. Is this the best way by which to accomplish what I'm trying, or will this attempt to use LINQ even work?

```
 //This is supposed to find 'contents' folders that have subdirectories, but it's unsuccessful

            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(txtbxOldFolder.Text);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories("*contents*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);                

            Var query = from folder in folders
                        where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length > 1
                        select folder.FullName.ToString();
            foreach (string str in query)
            {
                //this adds the path of any empty 'Contents' folder
                listNestedFolders.Add(str);
            }
```

Comment: Can you double check the samples you posted? The method signatures for GetDirectories are Directory.GetDirectories(String), Directory.GetDirectories(String, String), and Directory.GetDirectories(String, String, SearchOption).

Comment: For the code that I listed that works, it is exactly as it appears.

Comment: your code find folders that is empty.

Comment: whats the "\*contents\*"?  use this "contents\\".  and where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length > 0

Comment: Habib, as mentioned the first set of code finds empty *contents* folders. I'm trying to modify the code to find *contents* folders that contain subfolders.

Comment: your codes work correctly.  change length>1  to length>0

Comment: your code1 finds empty subfolders  that have inthe name   word "contents". in the directory  txtbxOldFolder.Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Var should be var -- and you want > 0.  This worked fine in LinqPad.  (Which I recommend for testing this stuff.)

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(txtbxOldFolder.Text);
DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories("*contents*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);                

var query = from folder in folders
            where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length > 0
            select folder.FullName.ToString();
```

Here is my LinqPad code which does just fine and shows you all the in-between steps.

```
void Main()
{
   DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\test");
   DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories(@"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

   var query2 = from folder in folders
                where folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length > 0
                select folder.FullName.ToString();

  folders.Select(f => f.GetFileSystemInfos()).Dump();
  query2.Dump();

  foreach (string str in query2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

Download LinqPad and try it out, it is worth it!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    public List<string> FindEmptyFolders(string FolderToSearchIn, string FolderNameToSearch, string FileExtension = "")
    {
        List<string> FolderList = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderToSearchIn, "*" + FolderNameToSearch + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        List<string> EmptyFolders = new List<string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileExtension))
            FolderList.ForEach(Folder => { if (System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder).Count() == 0) EmptyFolders.Add(Folder); });
        else
            FolderList.ForEach(Folder => { if (System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder, "*." + FileExtension).Count() == 0) EmptyFolders.Add(Folder); });
        return EmptyFolders;
    }
```

Usage:

```
foreach (string EmptyFolder in FindEmptyFolders(txtbxOldFolder.Text, "contents"))
            MessageBox.Show(EmptyFolder);
```